# How to static-serve all urls without '/' at the end except certain ones using express?

Tags: node.js, express, static, routes

I am setting up a Node.JS application using express, and I want `domain.tld/hey` to serve the `public/index/index.html` folder on the server (also containing other files such as .css or .js files).

However, I **DO NOT** want `domain.tld/hey/` to work (the `/` at the end is a problem for me) and in this case, I want to display a custom error page located at `public/error/index.html` on the server.

Finally, when accessing `domain.tld` or `domain.tld/`, I want to display a custom homepage located at `public/home/index.html` on the server.

**To summerize:**

- `domain.tld` or `domain.tld/` serves `public/home/index.html`
- `domain.tld/something` serves `public/index/index.html`
- `domain.tld/something/` or `domain.tld/some/thing` serves `public/error/index.html`

I already tried using `express.static('folder', { redirect: false })` but it doesn't display the index.html file and I can't get the other things to work.

I really don't know how to do it!

I fortunately don't have any code to show you guys as this is more a theorical problem, since I am beggining with expressjs.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers, and **please don't hesistate to ask for more details if you need some**!